# If Strain is change in dimension upon original dimension, then shouldn't shear strain be change in angle upon original angle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, stress-strain

Strain is defined as change in dimension upon original dimension. Shear strain expressed as Δx/l, doesn't seem to fit the earlier definition of strain.[image]

Comment: Please describe your effort to solve the problem. Note that shear strain is defined as the change in the shape of an object, as quantified by the change in a corner angle that was originally $90^\circ=\pi/2$. That's how angular geometry emerges.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Shear strain is defined as a ratio:

[image: Shear strain]

The shear strain is the ratio $y/x$, and this is equal to $\tan\theta$.